# Error on set_param SimulationCommand start - "memory allocation failed or you have no X connection"

Tags: python, matlab, simulink, mlabwrap

I'm trying to launch a **simulink** simulation using python script ( mlabwrap as python wrapper for matlab ). I open the simulink *.mdl file using:

```
open_system("thermo","loadonly");
```

I use set_param to initialize the simulation:

```
set_param("thermo", 'SimulationCommand', 'start');
```

This throws the following error:

**An error occurred when changing the simulation execution status. 
This may occurif a memory allocation failed or if you have no X connection**

If I just execute `sim("thermo")` everything works.

Unfortunatelly **I would like to use set_param** instead of sim.

How can I use `set_param("thermo", 'SimulationCommand', 'start');` and run it from terminal, without X server?

I'm using Matlab2009b on Ubuntu.

**EDIT:**

As it turned out, if I ran the simulation logged in as a user with X server, the everything works even with **set_param** ...

But I still wonder, if it is possible to run the simulation, without the X server running...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, you cannot start simulation using **set_param** without the X server:

["If you use matlab -nodisplay to start a session, you cannot use set_param to run your simulation."](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-the-set-param-command.html)

EDIT: official docs link ( as @Daniel pointed out )

Comment: [alternative link to the official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-the-set-param-command.html) (Contents is identical)

Comment: @Daniel am I right? (was not 100% ) matlab -nodisplay can be run without the x server, where set_param cannot be used to start the simulation, what basically means - set_param requires x server in order to start the simulation ?

Comment: I don't have any experience running matlab without x server, I can not answer your question.